# Setting up Typescript in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio, typescript

I am working on a project that utilizes AngularJS / Gulp and we are attempting to migrate to Angular.

Can someone inform me on how to properly allow the addition of .ts files in a project using VS 2015?  Steps performed so far:

```
- Installed Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler v2.9.1 (stable) via Nuget packet manager
- npm install @angular/core
- npm install @angular/upgrade 
- npm install @angular/platform-browser
- npm install @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
```

When I add a .ts file to my project I receive 2500 errors.  Some of which are shown below:

```
Error Build:'(' expected. app\node_modules\@angular\core\src\application_init.d.ts  17  
Error Build:'=' expected. \app\node_modules\@angular\core\src\application_init.d.ts 18      
Error Build:';' expected. \app\node_modules\@angular\core\src\application_ref.d.ts  185
```

What am I missing when adding a typescript file to my project that it causes so many issues?

EDIT:

I included a tsconfig.json file (below) and my error # reduced to 127.  Am I missing additional config options?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  The problem was I had a global and local install of typescript.  I needed to run "npm uninstall -g typescript" and "npm uninstall typescript".  From there do a fresh global install "npm install -g typescript"

Comment: Unless you needed a specific version for your project, the Typescript compiler should have come out-of-the-box with Visual Studio.